# Three js revision 71 at THREE.MeshFaceMaterial dont work proper

Tags: three.js, versions

While at the revision "66" when i use THREE.MeshFaceMaterial to load the textures of a tree model everything works fine.. and when i replace the three.min.js r66 with r71 the MeshFaceMaterial shows a black model.

Any ideas about r66-r71 changes?

i found a solution to my problem using r70 revision!(that was quick)! :)

Comment: most probably your textures are loading asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here. After blind investigation I found that some materials have opacity 0.
The solution is to modify your three r71 library where

```js
  // modifiers

  if ( m.transparency !== undefined ) {

   console.warn( 'THREE.Loader: transparency has been renamed to opacity' );
   m.opacity = m.transparency;

  }
```

change to

```js
  // modifiers

  if ( m.transparency !== undefined ) {

   console.warn( 'THREE.Loader: transparency has been renamed to opacity' );
   m.opacity = m.transparency;

  } else {
      m.opacity = 1;   
  }
```

Can't wait for r72!

Comment: Haven't test your answer cause i delivered the project i was workin! :D +1 vote but for your fine answer..seems correct!

Comment: Also I noticed that performance of 71 is better than 70. and/or that could be caused by upgrading to the newest version of Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, however, Pawel's answer did not work for me. If it doesn't work for you either, try this. Replace the following lines in r71:

```
    // modifiers

    if ( m.transparency !== undefined ) {

        console.warn( 'THREE.Loader: transparency has been renamed to opacity' );
        m.opacity = m.transparency;

    }
```

with this from r70:

```
    // modifiers

    if ( m.transparency ) {

        mpars.opacity = m.transparency;

    }
```

note: I'm not sure how this will affect your scene if you have transparency.